# Set keyboard to use only a specific language without let to use change language button. objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I try to obligate user to use only a specific language (my device language) and block the keyboard on this specific language. without allow him to change the language with the button.
what I did till now is to add a custom textfield:

```
@implementation customTextField

- (NSString *)langFromLocale:(NSString *)locale {
   NSRange r = [locale rangeOfString:@"_"];
   if (r.length == 0) r.location = locale.length;
     NSRange r2 = [locale rangeOfString:@"-"];
   if (r2.length == 0) r2.location = locale.length;
     return [[locale substringToIndex:MIN(r.location, r2.location)] 
     lowercaseString];
}

- (UITextInputMode *) textInputMode {
   NSString *myLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] 
   objectAtIndex:0];
   for (UITextInputMode *tim in [UITextInputMode activeInputModes]) {
       if ([[self langFromLocale:myLanguage ] isEqualToString:[self 
       langFromLocale:tim.primaryLanguage]]) return tim;
    }
    return [super textInputMode];
}


@end
```

this allowed me to set the language of keyboard, but when I wanted to remove the change language button I got an answer to change the keyboard from default to ascii. therefore, now the language is usually on english!!!!

waiting for an answer!!
thanx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this option is not possible in IOS keyboard, the button is default in this mode.